# Set VS 2013 Keyboard Shortcuts to different functions conditionally?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I have recently started working in Visual Studio 2013. Before this I worked extensively in Qt's IDE. One feature I really liked in Qt was that you could highlight a block of code and press CTRL+/ to comment each line in the block, then if every line in the block was already commented out, you could press CTRL+/ again to uncomment the lines. I figured out how to set the comment block shortcut in VS to CTRL+/ but I can't figure out a way to set the uncomment to that as well if everything is commented, like in Qt. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that just Ctrl-Shift-K or Ctrl + E, C

Comment: Ctrl-K + Ctrl-C for comment, and Ctrl-K + Ctrl-U for uncommenting.

Comment: I know how to do it with the built-in shortcuts, I just prefer using CRTL+/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't toggle comment like that in visual studio without using micro or third party extension, but I know for a fact that you can do it with **Resharper**, take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/a/860990/156563).